# Flutter set smooth_page_indicator in gridveiw builder

Tags: flutter

How can I set `smooth_page_indicator` in `GridView.builder` like this?

[image]

I've properly designed gridview like in image but indicator is not setting up.
How can I move indicator while scroll `gridView`? Is there any library for this?

Here is my code

```
 GridView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: list.length,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                // controller: _scrollController,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate:
                    const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                        maxCrossAxisExtent: 90,
                        childAspectRatio: 2 / 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 5),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column()
```

Here is code for `smooth_page_indicator`

```
Widget gridIndicator() => SmoothPageIndicator(
  controller: _scrollController,
  count: list.length,
  effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
      dotWidth: 8,
      dotHeight: 8,
      spacing: 5.0,
      dotColor: Colors.grey,
      activeDotColor: Colors.red));
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: @Diwyansh Kindly responds.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about it, Let me go through the code and I will share the result.

Comment: Try my answers and revert please.

Comment: Have you checked?

Comment: I'll check it tonight , I was outside the city.

Comment: Okay, sure let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

To use `Smooth Progress Indicator` with **GridView.builder** you need to `calculate` the length of the `indicators` that you can get by dividing `list length by count of items` that are visible on screen at once and also have to use **PageController**. I'm Sharing a reference `example` for that you can `customize` it as per your need.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List list = [
    "Product 1",
    "Product 2",
    "Product 3",
    "Product 4",
    "Product 5",
    "Product 6",
    "Product 7",
    "Product 8",
    "Product 9",
    "Product 10",
    "Product 11"
  ];
  PageController _scrollController = PageController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(double.parse("${list.length / 2}").round());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 400,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemCount: list.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 100,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg"),
                          ),
                          Text(list[index]),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 7,
                      childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 3),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SmoothPageIndicator(
                controller: _scrollController,
                count: double.parse("${list.length / 6}").round(),
                effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                    dotWidth: 8,
                    dotHeight: 8,
                    spacing: 5.0,
                    dotColor: Colors.grey,
                    activeDotColor: Colors.red)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For dynamic height you can use Flexible widget it's all about your UI and needs.

Comment: Sure. let me know the result as well..:)

Comment: facing `type 'ScrollPositionWithSingleContext' is not a subtype of type '_PagePosition' in type cast` error

Comment: Share your updated code.

Comment: updated my code.

Comment: I can't generate the error your code is also working fine my side. Try attaching screenshot with error

Comment: @Vaidarbhi try to add `shrinkWrap: true`

Comment: @MansoorMalik you issues is reaolved? and Vaidarbhi in your code I guess the is with width of the Gridview's parent because it's not allowing Gridview's child to go outside .

Comment: @Diwyansh no still facing this issue

Comment: which issue now?

Comment: same problem, let me add some changes

Comment: Sure just add it.

Comment: Kindly now check it.

Comment: What is the issue now didn't get it?

Comment: I want a indicator like in image when I scroll grid then indicator should move along

Comment: @Diwyansh any solution ?

Comment: I think the example I have provided working in the same way?

Comment: but I want slider indicator, if you can download noon app then watch its homepage where horizontal `gridView` is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241033/discussion-between-mansoor-malik-and-diwyansh).

Comment: I'll to send you DartPad link with the working functionality.

Comment: @Diwyansh I've asked another question please responds on it 
 [Here is the link of that question][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70697744/flutter-after-record-video-go-to-next-page

Comment: @MansoorMalik the code I have added in my answer is working fine my side doesn't it working fine your side?