# Flutter Show thumbnail of recorded video on next page?

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I want to Pick video from my gallery and then after it I want to go next page and save thumbnail in container. I've searched a lot but couldn't find suitable answer.

Here is my code for open Gallery

```
     File video;

  Future openGallery(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      final video = await ImagePicker().pickVideo(source: source);
      if (video == null) return;
      final videoTemp = File(video.path);
      this.video = videoTemp;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Failed to pick video: $e');
    }
  }

InkWell(
                  onTap: () async{
                   await openGallery(context, ImageSource.gallery);
                    Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
                        Post(video: video,)));
                  },
```

Second Page (here I want to show video thumbnail in container)

```
class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  final File video;
  Post({Key key, this.video}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PostState createState() => _PostState();
}

class _PostState extends State<Post> {
  VideoPlayerController playerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    playerController = VideoPlayerController.file(widget.video.path)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    playerController.dispose();
  }

Center(
                child: playerController.value.isInitialized
                    ? InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    width: 75.0,
                    height: 120.0,
                    child: VideoPlayer(playerController),
                  ),
                )
                    : CircularProgressIndicator()),
```

Comment: Are you saving this video locally?

Comment: I'm picking Video from galley and want to go next screen , and there is a container where I want to show that picked video thumbnail. Its Urgent please I've to deliver this project today

Comment: Let me reproduce your scenario.

Comment: ok waiting for your kind response

Comment: I've edited my code.

Comment: in this parameter  video: video.path, I think you need to pass video  not video.path. And is you video playing over next page?

Comment: @Diwyansh Hi,
below answer is correct but I'm facing issue that app freez and then crash here is exception `sendappfreezeevent failed!`. I've updated my code

Comment: Hi, sorry I wasn't available for sometime. Well sendappfreezeevent happen when you have connectivity issue in your mobile app so I'll suggest you to check permissions first.

Comment: Its ok! I've checked it, it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Edits to your first snippet:

```
XFile video;

Future openGallery(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
      final video = await ImagePicker().pickVideo(source: source);
      if (video != null) {
        print(video.path);
        await navigator.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Post(
                video: video,
                ),
          ),
        );
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Failed to pick video: $e');
    }
  }
```

Edits to your second snippet:

```
class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  final XFile video;
  Post({Key key, this.video}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PostState createState() => _PostState();
}

class _PostState extends State<Post> {
  bool comment = true;
  bool save = true;

  VideoPlayerController playerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    playerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.video.path))
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    playerController.dispose();
  }
  //....
  Center(
      child: playerController.value.initialized
         ? Container(
            width: 100.0,
            height: 56.0,
            child: VideoPlayer(playerController),
           )
        : CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
 //....
```

Comment: facing error `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.` on `playerController = VideoPlayerController.file(widget.video.path)`

Comment: Make it like this:

`playerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.video.path))`

Comment: after removing `The argument type 'XFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'.`

Comment: Edited my previous comment, please check it again.

Comment: thanks bro it works , but I've one issue when I press back I cant show my gallery

Comment: when I go to next screen after pick video it shows the camera open screen(tap on button , open camera and from there I'm opening my gallery) while moving to next screen

Comment: Hi buddy I'm facing issue after click video and show its thumbnail. app crash after some minutes

Comment: Did you follow all the instructions mentioned on the plugin page? 
`https://pub.dev/packages/video_player`, like maybe your app doesn't have internet permissions? You can share any further code if you have.

Comment: I'm facing `sendappfreezeevent failed!` issue

Comment: Make a separate thread for your new questions instead of asking on comments.

Comment: I've closed this project